# Cannot GET (path) Reactjs, nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, authentication, react-router

I am trying to serve my react app from Nodejs, but I am getting a `GET` error which is odd because when I run npm start and run the react start script all works well, but once I use node.js it doesn't work. Also if I navigate to a route by typing it in or trying to navigate backward it throws an error. For example, when you first navigate to the homepage it takes you to a login page, and if I go to another page  and then hit back it throws a `GET` error even though it worked beforehand.

## Node.js Server

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();

require('dotenv').config()

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());



app.get('/', async (req,res) => {

    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
    
    });




    app.listen(3000, () => {
        console.log(`Server listening on 3000`);
    });
```

## React index.js

```
*/
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";
import { Router, Route, Switch, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import { Auth0Provider } from "@auth0/auth0-react";

// core components
import Admin from "layouts/Admin.js";
import Authentication from 'layouts/Authentication';
import DashboardPage from "views/Dashboard/Dashboard.js";
import UserProfile from "views/UserProfile/UserProfile.js";

import "assets/css/material-dashboard-react.css?v=1.9.0";

const hist = createBrowserHistory();

ReactDOM.render(
  <Auth0Provider
  domain={`${process.env.REACT_APP_Auth0_Domain}`}
  clientId={`${process.env.REACT_APP_Auth0_ClientID}`}
  redirectUri={`http://localhost:3000/dashboard`}
  >
  <Router history={hist}>
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/login"  component={Authentication} />
      <Route path="/dashboard" component={DashboardPage} />
      <Route path="/user"  component={UserProfile} />
      <Redirect from='/' to='/login' />
    </Switch>
  </Router>,
  </Auth0Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

## Routes.js

```
// @material-ui/icons
import Dashboard from "@material-ui/icons/Dashboard";
import Person from "@material-ui/icons/Person";

// core components/views for Admin layout
import DashboardPage from "views/Dashboard/Dashboard.js";
import UserProfile from "views/UserProfile/UserProfile.js";
import Authentication from './layouts/Authentication';

const dashboardRoutes = [
  {
    path: "/dashboard",
    name: "Invoice Dashboard",
    icon: Dashboard,
    component: DashboardPage,
  },
  {
    path: "/login",
    name: "Login",
    icon: Dashboard,
    component: Authentication
  },
  {
    path: "/user",
    name: "User Profile",
    icon: Person,
    component: UserProfile,
  }
];

export default dashboardRoutes;
```

Comment: Is the `Routes.js` file relevant, or used anywhere? It seems to duplicate the routes defined in your index.js file. Are you trying to use server-side-rendering (SSR)? https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom-server.html

Comment: I can't understand what he wants to say can you be a little clear

Comment: The routes file is used in one other place to help make the items in the navbar but that’s it. Yes trying to do sever side rendering and I have all my react apps using this set up with express just first time I have run into this issue not sure what I am missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior is coming from your `express` app in the node.js server.

**See your statement**:

```
app.get('/', async (req,res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html')); 
});
```

Your app is only returning the `index.html` file when you request the path `'/'`. Basically, your react router is only established with an initial request to `'/'` - allowing react `Link` (e.g) elements to route correctly thereafter. This explains why typing in a deeplink (e.g `'/example-path'`) and hitting the back button raise errors.

**Structure your express routes to handle specific URLs, and return with the `index.js` file for all others. This will allow react router to handle your front end routes, and still allow express to handle the back end routes.**

```
// An example api endpoint that returns a list of items
app.get('/api/getList', (req, res) => {
    var list = ["item1", "item2", "item3"];
    res.json(list);
    console.log('Sent list of items');
});

// Handles any requests that don't match the ones above
app.get('*', (req, res) =>{
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html')); 
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your time, so if I understand correctly if I use the wild card `*` it should cover the other routes such as /dashboard?

Comment: It should, yes.

Comment: Perfect that worked, I just put it under all my other routes, thank you.